# Sending notifications from my laptop to a set of mobile devices

Tags: android, google-cloud-messaging

I would like to send notification(s) to a subset of mobile devices from my laptop. The notification would contain a one line text message. I plan using GCM services for the above but I still do not have much idea about the sequence of steps I should be following.

Also, I would like the mobile devices to be able to send its location(co-ordinates) and a one line text message to the nearest server (I plan on having a couple of designated servers).

What are the tools to be used and how should I approach this problem?

Comment: question is too broad, and can't be answered correctly

Answer (score 0):

Use FCM(Firebase cloud messaging) to send push notification to all mobile device. Its best and easiest way to send push notification to all registered mobile device.

[Firebase Notification](https://firebase.google.com/docs/notifications/android/console-audience)

Also you can use Firebase Realtime Database for store device locations.

[Firebase Realtime Database](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/android/start/)

Answer (score 0):

You can use GCM(Which you are already using) or FCM(Firebase Cloud Messaging, recommended) along with the well known and free to use urban airship.  The steps are simple:

1) get an account in urban airship
2) add a receiver on your manifest to listen to notifications
3) on your application activity add a piece of code containing the "takeOff" method.
4) create a class which extends urban airship and override the methods
5) get "API key" from firebase and put that key where it is needed on urban airship.
6) get the config file from urban airship and replace the last line of the config file with your firebase "sender id"

Now you can send notifications to all the devices.  You can also send notifications only to test devices by obtaining the channel id of the particular device and adding it to the list of test devices in urban airship.

Answer (score 0):

I think you should try Firebase instead of GCM because they provide a userpanel to send notification from there and also it's a upgraded part of GCM.

simply you can go on https://console.firebase.google.com.

1. Create your app.

   2. get the code to impliment notification in your app.
   3. follow the steps given by firebase.